# Can't call constructor from another class

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to call a constructor from another class.
Main class:

```
package com.southerland.Tutorial;

import com.southerland.Tutorial.display.Display;

public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Display("Title!", 300, 300);
    }

}
```

2nd Class:

```
package com.southerland.Tutorial.display;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Display{

    private JFrame frame;

    private String title;
    private int width, height;

    public Display(String title, int width, int height){
        this.title = title;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;   
        createDisplay();
    }
    private void createDisplay(){
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The error is one the "new Display("Title!", 300, 300);" part and it says "The constructor Display(String, int, int) is undefined" any idea on how to fix?

Comment: Looks like it should work to me. Have you tried re-building and cleaning the project?

Comment: You should check whether you actually ended up with a directory structure that matches your package hierarchy and your .java files are in their respective dirs.

Comment: Please don't add 'solved' to your question title, or put an answer in the question post. If you have found a  solution you think could be helpful to future visitors, put it in an answer post below. You can even mark it as accepted.

Comment: Do you have two classes with the same name ? anyway try likethis **new com.southerland.Tutorial.display.Display("Title!", 300, 300);**